# Load a page as a dialog in asp.net

Tags: asp.net

I am working on a login page. In the main page, when a user clicks the login button, I want to deactivate the main page and to show the login form. The main page must stay disabled till the user finish in the login process.

Can any one tell me how can i do this?

Answer (score 4):

You might find [jquery UI dialog](http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/) a useful plugin for achieving this task and especially its [modal form](http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/#modal-form) functionality.

Comment: but it's to hard to be understood i diddn't work with j query before

Comment: if there is another way tell me please?